# Boost any_range performance: std::prev(iterator) versus --iterator

Tags: c++, performance, boost, c++11, iterator

I've recently begun to prefer the free functions `std::next` and `std::prev` to explicitly copying and incrementing/decrementing iterators. Now, I am seeing weird behavior in a pretty specific case, and I would appreciate any help demystifying it.

I have an interpolation/extrapolation function operating on a `boost::any_range` of some `X_type`. The full definition of the range type is:

```
boost::any_range <
    const X_type,
    boost::random_access_traversal_tag,
    const X_type,
    std::ptrdiff_t
>
```

The `any_range`, in this particular case, is assigned from an `iterator_range` holding two pointers to `const X_type`, which serves as an `X_type` view of about half of the `data()` area of a `vector<char>`.

Compiling my application in MSVC 2010, everything works just fine.
Compiling the same code in MinGW g++ 4.7.0, it seemed to hang in one particular location, which I've then narrowed down to this (slightly abbreviated):

```
// Previously ensured conditions:
// 1) xrange is nonempty;
// 2) yrange is the same size as xrange.

auto x_equal_or_greater =
    std::lower_bound(std::begin(xrange),std::end(xrange),xval);

if (x_equal_or_greater == std::end(xrange))
{
    return *yit_from_xit(std::prev(x_equal_or_greater),xrange,yrange);
}
```

Stepping through the code in gdb, I found out it wasn't getting stuck, just taking a very long time to return from the single `std::prev` call - which in libstdc++ is implemented in terms of `std::advance` and ultimately the `+=` operator.

By merely replacing the `return` line with:

```
auto xprev=x_equal_or_greater;
--xprev;
return *yit_from_xit(xprev,xrange,yrange);
```

Performance is great again, and there's virtually no delay.

I am aware of the overhead of using type-erased iterators (those of `any_range`), but even so, are the two cases above really supposed to carry such different costs? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'll try to verify this tomorrow, but could it be that your particular library's `std::prev` is erroneously trying to advance the iterator by `size_type(-1)` (which is to say a very large unsigned integer) instead of reverse-advancing it by `1`? That would certainly lead to a hang... but it would also almost certainly be a bug in the library.

Comment: std::prev is implemented with std::advance. I wonder if this has to do with the std::iterator_traits<...> of boost::random_access_traversal_tag. GCC specializes std::advance for random access, bidirectional, and input iterators. So, does boost::random_access_traversal_tag deduce to the correct tag in GCC's STL functions?

Looking at the boost code (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/boost/iterator/iterator_categories.hpp), I'm not sure how it could since there's no reference to the std iterator categories. I found the relevant GCC code in /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h.

Comment: @SplinterOfChaos: FYI, If you dig through range implementation, any_range uses any_range_iterators, which derive from iterator_facade.  It uses some Template Metaprogramming to determine the appropriate STL iterator_category from the input boost traversal tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after responding to [SplinterOfChaos's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281298/boost-any-range-performance-stdpreviterator-versus-iterator#comment17991728_11281298), I realized something.  The problem is in your use of the any_range.  In particular, the 3rd argument, which indicates that the Reference argument is a `const int`. In the boost iterator facade, when the reference is not a real reference, it will either use `std::input_iterator_tag`, or not provide an STL equivalent tag.

It has to do with the fact, that strictly speaking, all forward, bidirectional, and random access STL iterators must use a real reference for their reference type.  From 24.2.5 of the C++11 standard:

> A class or a built-in type X satisfies the requirements of a forward iterator if
>
> — X satisfies the requirements of an input iterator (24.2.3),
>
> — X satisfies the DefaultConstructible requirements (17.6.3.1),
>
> — **if X is a mutable iterator, reference is a reference to T; if X is a const iterator, reference is a reference to const T**,
>
> — the expressions in Table 109 are valid and have the indicated semantics, and
>
> — objects of type X offer the multi-pass guarantee, described below.

In this case, it's returning an `std::input_iterator_tag` when queried for its `iterator_category`, which causes the call to `std::prev()` veer into *Undefined Behavior*.

Either way, the solution is to change (if possible) your use of `boost::any_range` to the following:

```
  boost::any_range <
        const X_type,
        boost::random_access_traversal_tag,
        const X_type&,
        std::ptrdiff_t
    >
```

This will cause it to have an `iterator_category` of `std::random_access_iterator_tag`, and will perform the operation as you originally expected.

Comment: This seems to be it. I've since then run into related issues elsewhere in my code, where standard library code would refuse to play nice with iterators it couldn't place a neat tag on, e.g VS2012's library actually has `static_assert`s in place which prevent all these iterator utilities from even compiling with such arguments. Correspondingly I've already changed some of my types, and can't go back to try this particular change right now; but again, this seems spot on. Many thanks.

Comment: why `boost` traversal tags are replaced with their `std` counterparts in the first place? What's the point in having them at all then?